# Probability of relations in a network

Tags: graph-theory

Imagine, i have a random graph with $n$ nodes representing people. Between every two nodes there is an edge representing friendship with probability $p_2$. These edges are independently generated, so I expect there to be $\binom{n}{2}p_2$ friends. Now, imagine, I count (observe) the number of times that 3 people are all friends of each other in this world: $\binom{n}{3} p_3$. Therefor, I expect the probability of three random people being friends to be $p_3$. (probabilities $p_2, p_3 \in [0..1]$)

I'm trying to calculate the probability that any 4 people in my world are all friends with each other. Without knowing $p_3$ I would estimate the probability to be $p_2^6$. But obviously knowing $p_3$ influences the probability. For example if $\frac{p_3}{p_2}$ increases, I expect the friendships to be denser and thus more 4 people will form groups. I have trouble however finding a formula to express this probability, because the probabilities that the different subgroups of 3 people are friends are not independent. And if I take four random people the probability that at least 3 subgroups of three people are friends is the same as that at least 4 subgroups of three people are friends.

Could you provide any advice on how one typically calculates such a problem or what to search for? By what factor does $\frac{p_3}{p_2}$ increase the probability of a third connecting edge in presence of two edges? I would assume one would somehow express this using conditional probabilities, although I can't seem to figure out exactly how.

Comment: The meaning of your notation is obscure. Presumably "$p$" by itself means "probability of"; evidently the "$p_i$" are numbers in the range $[0,1]$; and likely the value of "$\text{friends}$" is logical. But how are these related to "people"?  Exactly how are they "generated"?  Due to this vagueness, by the time one gets to the second paragraph your post is unintelligible. Could you edit it to include explanations of the notation and to clarify your random generation process?

Comment: @whuber You're absolutely right, I hope it is clearer now?

Comment: It is clearer, but I should point out that you appear to move back and forth between probabilities, frequencies, and estimates without distinguishing them. This could be confusing you and it likely will confuse your readers, too. You might try explaining things in words. For instance, are you thinking of people as $n$ nodes of a graph and "friends" as *independently* generated edges, each with probability $p_2$? Or is $p_2$ the *observed relative frequency* of edges in a particular graph? Such English descriptions can help resolve the ambiguities of your notation and clarify your question.

Comment: @whuber I tried to clarify the issues you mentioned now

Comment: Thanks. You still seem to confuse probabilities with observed frequencies. If I'm interpreting this correctly, then $p_2$ and $n$ ought to completely determine the *probabilities* of three, four, ..., etc. people being friends, so isn't your question simply what are the formulas for them?

Comment: @whuber Yes, but the complication is the observation that there are $\binom{n}{3}p_3$ triangles. Therefor the probability of three people being friends is not $p_2^3$ but $p_3$ and this will have implications on the probability that 4 people are all friends.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is simple:

For $n$ nodes with probability $p$ of a connecting edge, the probabilty $p_n$ that a given group of all selected nodes have mutual connecting edges is:

$p_n = p^ \frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}$

That is, the combined probability that the required number of unique edges required occur concurrently.

**To illustrate:**

for $n = 2$:

$p_n = p_{12}$

[image]

for $n = 3$:

$p_n = (p_{12})(p_{13})(p_{23})$

[image]

for $n = 4$:

$p_n = (p_{12})(p_{13})(p_{14})(p_{23})(p_{24})(p_{34})$

[image]

As the probability of any connecting edge has been defined as $p$, there is no need to further delimit the probability of any two specific nodes having a connecting edge.

Therefore:

for $n = 2$:

$p_n = p^1$            (identity)

for $n = 3$:

$p_n = p^3$

for $n = 4$:

$p_n = p^6$

The probability of an edge occuring between two nodes is not affected by whether one of the nodes has other connecting edges.

**Mutual Inclusion Factor**

If, however, you're looking for a probability $p_n$ given a conditional $p(s)$ that is dependent on the number of shared other connections $s$:

$p(s)$ = probability of a shared edge given $s$ mutual connections to other nodes

**To illustrate:**

for $n = 2$ and $s_{12} = 2$:

$p_n = p(s_{12})$

[image]

for $n = 3$:

[image]

$p_n = (p(s_{12}))(p(s_{13}))(p(s_{23}))$

for $n = 4$:

$p_n = (p(s_{12}))(p(s_{13}))(p(s_{14}))(p(s_{23}))(p(s_{24}))(p(s_{34}))$

etc.

$p(s)$ values would have to be determined through an analysis of your particular network- (what is the probability of two nodes sharing an edge given that they share connections to $s$ other nodes?) as would $p$ in the original case.